# jQuery datatable header elements not aligned

Tags: datatables

I am using datatable, and everything is working fine. But header elements are not properly aligned.

[image: Datatable header]

**References:**

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're only showing us how the scripts are loaded. We need to see CSS  in order to see how everything is arranged.

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @eclipsis I am using only these css libraries which are from bootstrap and jquery datatable libraries. Do you want to see those css? Should I upload them live and give you link?

Comment: @jonmrich https://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html this is how it will look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who tried to help me. I found out the solution. Bootstrap css is effecting the datatable css.

Bootstrap is overrriding the width of select element in header. I just put custom css to fix the width. Problem solved.

```
.dataTables_wrapper select{
    display: inline !important;
    width: 60px !important;
}
```

Now its looking like this:
[image]

Comment: There's a plugin for Datatables to enable compatibility for Bootstrap that might be worth you taking a look at: https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap